# Check if a particular jframe is open from another frame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, frame

I have 3 JFrames which use a common JFrame for the purpose of selecting a customer from the complete list. These are the 3 JFrames.

1. AddPayment
2. AddInvoice
3. AddPurchase

All these interfaces use a common JFrame called SelectCustomer which has a listbox from which the user can select one customer from the complete customer list. The name of the selected customer should appear in the JFrame which called the SelectCustomer JFrame.

I know I can use a static jTextField to access and set the value. What I want to know is how can I know which of the above 3 called this SelectCustomer JFrame so that I can decide where the selected value should go.

One of the gui which causes the SelectCustomer JFrame to appear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTB3e.png

Select Customer JFrame:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo00n.png

I hope my question is clear. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a button to open the frame and then use this in the same action listener

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!frame2.isVisible())
            frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I want to know which one of the 3 frames called the SelectCustomer frame, from the SelectCustomer frame.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, maybe this answer seems silly, but have you tried sending some reference when you are calling the class, either from the 3 JFrames?, since I think there is no function that can tell you who called the current JFrame.

So, when you call the SelectCustomerFrame, you could do something like

> new SelectCustomerFrame(whatever params, this);

It will require three different constructors in the SelectCustomerFrame in order to sort out who actually called the SelectCustomerFrame, each of them capturing the distinct classes.

Hope to have sourted out your troubles.